# Узнать последнюю дату прочтения файла

Tags: java, c++, файлы

Доброго времени суток. Можно ли узнать когда последний раз был прочитан определённый файл? Не создан, изменён, а именно прочитан. При помощи с++ или Java это возможно? Подскажите как.

Comment: насколько я могу судить, без функций ОС это решить невозможно, а потому платформозависимо, а потому Вам надо указать свою ОС.

Answer (score 1):

под linux смотрите atime, пример чтения метаданных есть по ссылке
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)

windows NTFS по умолчанию не трекает дату последнего прочтения, хотя можно включить через реестр.
https://serverfault.com/questions/351777/how-can-i-know-when-a-file-was-last-read-or-accessed-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

С использованием WinAPI, не стоит забывать про часовой пояс.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\JagailoPC\\Desktop\\Пусто.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile != NULL)
    {
        FILETIME fc, fa, fw;
        if (GetFileTime(hFile, &fc, &fa, &fw) != 0)
        {
            SYSTEMTIME cm;
            if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&fa, &cm) != 0)
            {
                cout << "Open/Last access: " << cm.wDay << "." << cm.wMonth << "." << cm.wYear << " " << cm.wHour << ":" << cm.wMinute << endl;
            }
            if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&fc, &cm) != 0)
            {
                cout << "Creation: " << cm.wDay << "." << cm.wMonth << "." << cm.wYear << " " << cm.wHour << ":" << cm.wMinute << endl;
            }
            if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&fw, &cm) != 0)
            {
                cout << "Write: " << cm.wDay << "." << cm.wMonth << "." << cm.wYear << " " << cm.wHour << ":" << cm.wMinute << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "GetFileTime error.\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Open file error.\n";
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @nick если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.